# Flask too many redirects for SSL

Tags: python, ssl, flask

I am trying to force http to https in my flask app but I keep getting the error "Too Many Redirects" in the 2 methods I am trying to use. I have tried and read similar SO questions but it has not solved it.
WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

Here is the FIRST method using a decorated function:

```
def ssl_required(fn):
@wraps(fn)
def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
    if request.is_secure:
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return redirect(request.url.replace("http://", "https://"))

    return decorated_view
```

Here is my view function:

```
@main.route('/stats', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@ssl_required
@login_required
def stats():

    users = User.query.all()

    return render_template('stats.html', users=users)
```

HERE IS THE SECOND METHOD:

```
@auth.before_app_request
def before_request():
    if request.url.startswith('http://'):
        url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
        code = 301
        return redirect(url, code=code)
```

The view function for this is:

```
@main.route('/stats', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def stats():

    users = User.query.all()

    return render_template('stats.html', users=users)
```